# boost tcp socket stuck in write_some

Tags: tcp, boost-asio

I have a boost tcp ip socket that is stuck in write_some function
The receiver part is stuck in a dead lock(which is another problem not linked to tcp socket). I succeeded to simulate the problem with just sleeping for ever in the receiver thread.

Even if i reboot the sender it hangs on the same line

Is there a way to set a timeout in case it is stuck in this state to restart the connection? If i use async_write_some will it be a solution?

When i do gstack on the sender side  i can see it is stuck in the write_some function in the call to poll() from /lib64/libc.so.6. In the following line

```
socket->write_some(boost::asio::buffer(pData ,nLength, error);
```

Receiver netstat
[image]

Sender netstat, i saw some cases where the netstat ouptut is fin_wait1 and in some case it is in established(but still the code is stuck in write_some)

[image]

To initialize the sender socket

```
socket = boost::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_service,boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint, 
boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(),portNumber)))
    // Set a deadline for the asynchronous operation.
boost::asio::deadline_timer pConnectTimer = ...;
pConnectTimer->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
boost::asio::socket_base::keep_alive option(true);
socket->set_option(option);
// Start the asynchronous connect itself.
socket->async_connect(endpoint,boost::bind(&CrXdrQueuetoSocket::ConnectCallback, this, std::ref(pi_xdrTarget),
        socket,boost::asio::placeholders::error));

//Poll io service only one time
io_service .poll_one();
```

Comment: Something wrong here. FIN_WAIT_1 means you have closed the socket (sent a FIN) and are waiting for the peer to ACK the FIN. You therefore can't also be blocked in `send()` at the same time.

Comment: There is definitely more to it than what meets the eye. Provide us with a minimal reproducible example so that we can see what is happening with the sender socket. Also, you might want to take a look at the actual packet flow with `tcpdump` or `wireshark` or what have you.

Answer (score 0):

Using my crystal ball: are you passing `fd`s around (e.g. for thirdparty or legacy code to use)?

You might be running into a classic pitfall.

In socket code there needs to be one (1) owner of the socket who gets to close it. In concurrent code it's extremely important to make sure that nobody else has a copy of the fd after that point in time, because that opens it up for race conditions.

For example, the same fd wil be re-used after it was closed, and another thread may then use the fd thinking it was still the old connection.

This mistake seems unlikely, but people are prone to make it because they feel "it's safe, the fd is closed, so all later operations will fail anyway".

I've swatted bugs in code where at rare times, the application would accidentally be fuzz-testing the database server, because they would be sending arbitrary data to a connection that was re-opened to mysql.

Note that instead of `close()` you can `shutdown()` which makes all pending operations cancel and new operations fail, WITHOUT releasing the fd for re-use.