# Boost ASIO and file descriptor reuse

Tags: boost-asio

I have multi-threaded (linux) server that registers async_writes and async_reads on the same native file descriptor through a socket object. I noticed under very heavy load when the server was dropping connections, on a very rare occasion a client would receive a garbled first message.

Tracking it down, the async_read detects an error on the socket and closes the socket. This closes the native file descriptor. If that file descriptor is reused before the original async_write has a chance to fire, it will find its native file descriptor valid and proceed to send its message (which is really a message from a previous session).

The only way I could see to fix this was to make the the async_read and async_write callbacks know if there were other callbacks registered and only close the socket if it were the last one.

Has anyone seen this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen it but it sounds plausible. Although I am surprised to see a new native file descriptor getting the exact same number than a recently closed descriptor.

You might want to put the socket in a shared_ptr and query shared_ptr::is_unique in both async_read and async_write. That'd be the easiest way to let the other callback know if both callbacks are registered. If is_unique is true you can be sure that no one else is still using this socket and can close it.

So if the connection gets dropped, async_read can check is_unique. If it is true, close the socket. And let go of the shared_ptr in either case.

Then, when async_write also fires it will find is_unique true and can close the socket, unless async_read has already closed it.

The only drawback is of course: async_write has to fire also (perhaps with an error code) in order to close the socket.

Comment: I've seen exacftly that. And more people have fallen to the same trap - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57875513/85371. By the way shared/unique pointers really don't solve anything here: `boost::asio::basic_socket<>` is already move-only and uniquely owns its handle. The real issue is that the handle is externally closed - not by its owner.

Comment: shared_ptr would help _you_ alleviate this problem. shared_ptr<socket> will help you with the 'and only close the socket if it were the last one.' part.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I've seen exactly this in production code. (Much fun: we would be talking a proprietary protocol on a TCP socket to mysql server). The problem is when some thread "handles" (mis-handles) errors by closing sockets using the native handle (fd). Don't. Use shutdown (perhaps with cancel) instead and let the destructor take care of close. Of course, the real problem is the non-owning copies of the handle (fd) that are the cause of the resource race.

Critical Note:

> *Tracking it down, the async_read detects an error on the socket and closes the socket. This closes the native file descriptor*

That's patently UNTRUE for Asio itself. Perhaps you have (third-party) code in the completion handlers doing that, but as I mention above, you cannot afford to do that.